# Is it possible / advisable to return a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I'm using the ranges library to help filer data in my classes, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<int> v) : vec(v) {}

    std::vector<int> getEvens() const
    {
        auto evens = vec | ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return ! (i % 2); });
        return std::vector<int>(evens.begin(), evens.end());
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

In this case, a new vector is constructed in the `getEvents()` function. To save on this overhead, I'm wondering if it is possible / advisable to return the range directly from the function?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    using RangeReturnType = ???;

    MyClass(std::vector<int> v) : vec(v) {}

    RangeReturnType getEvens() const
    {
        auto evens = vec | ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return ! (i % 2); });
        // ...
        return evens;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

If it is possible, are there any lifetime considerations that I need to take into account?

I am also interested to know if it is possible / advisable to pass a range in as an argument, or to store it as a member variable. Or is the ranges library more intended for use within the scope of a single function?

Comment: Why not return `auto`?

Comment: Maybe all you want is a `getView` function that returns `vec` as a view, with `even` being a free lambda that can be called by `views::filter`

Comment: The only reason you want to return it as a `vector` is if you know that every time you calls it, you want to store that as a new `vector`. Otherwise, you can always return a view and create a vector of it if needed.

Comment: How do I even create a view to return it?

Comment: I figured that one out... auto range = container | ranges::views::all;

Comment: @Ranoiaetep, I entirely agree that allocating new memory is unnecessary if I'm not going to store the vector. So what are my options if I want to access a subset (for instance even numbers)? The Ranges library seems promising, but I'm a little apprehensive about this returning auto. Are there any other approaches I should be considering, with or without the Ranges library?

Answer (score 5):

In c++23, you can use [std::generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator) and `co_yield` [std::ranges::elements_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/elements_of)

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<int> v) : vec(v) {}

    std::generator<int> getEvens() const
    {
        auto evens = vec | std::ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return ! (i % 2); });
        co_yield std::ranges::elements_of(evens);
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}};
    for (int i : mc.getEvens()) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Working demo (GCC 13.1 without `std::ranges::elements_of`): https://godbolt.org/z/oehd59oEz

Answer (score 4):

This was asked in op's comment section, but I think I will respond it in the answer section:

> The Ranges library seems promising, but I'm a little apprehensive about this returning auto.

Remember that even with the addition of `auto`, C++ is a strongly typed language. In your case, since you are returning `evens`, then the return type will be the same type of `evens`. (technically it will be the value type of `evens`, but `evens` was a value type anyways)

<s>In fact, you probably really don't want to type out the return type manually: `std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<const std::vector<int>>, MyClass::getEvens() const::<decltype([](int i) {return ! (i % 2);})>>` (141 characters)</s>

---

- As mentioned by @Caleth in the comment, in fact, this wouldn't work either as `evens` was a lambda defined inside the function, and the type of two different lambdas will be different even if they were basically the same, so there's literally no way of getting the full return type here.

---

While there might be debates on whether to use `auto` or not in different cases, but I believe most people would just use `auto` here. Plus your `evens` was declared with `auto` too, typing the type out would just make it less readable here.

---

> So what are my options if I want to access a subset (for instance even numbers)? Are there any other approaches I should be considering, with or without the Ranges library?

Depends on how you would access the returned data and the type of the data, you might consider returning `std::vector<T*>`.

`views` are really supposed to be viewed from start to end. While you could use `views::drop` and `views::take` to limit to a single element, it doesn't provide a subscript operator (yet).

There will also be computational differences. `vector` need to be computed beforehand, where `views` are computed while iterating. So when you do:

```
for(auto i : myObject.getEven())
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Under the hood, it is basically doing:

```
for(auto i : myObject.vec)
{
    if(!(i % 2)) std::cout << i;
}
```

Depends on the amount of data, and the complexity of computations, `views` might be a lot faster, or about the same as the `vector` method. Plus you can easily apply multiple filters on the same range without iterating through the data multiple times.

In the end, you can always store the `view` in a `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec2(evens.begin(), evens.end());
```

---

So my suggestions is, if you have the **ranges library**, then you **should** use it.

<sup>If not, then `vector<T>`, `vector<T*>`, `vector<index>` depending on the size and copiability of T.</sup>

Comment: You can't type out the type of evens, because the lambda `[](int i) {return ! (i % 2);}` in the body is a different type to the lambda `[](int i) {return ! (i % 2);}` in the declaration

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range), a range is just something on which you can call `begin` and `end`. Nothing more than that.

For instance, you can use the result of `begin(range)`, which is an iterator, to traverse the `range`, using the `++` operator to advance it.

In general, looking back at the concept I linked above, you can use a range whenever the conext code only requires to be able to call `begin` and `end` on it.

Whether this is advisable or enough depends on what you need to do with it. Clearly, if your intention is to pass `evens` to a function which expects a `std::vector` (for instance it's a function you cannot change, and it calls `.push_back` on the entity we are talking about), you clearly have to make a `std::vector` out of `filter`'s output, which I'd do via

```cpp
auto evens = vec | ranges::views::filter(whatever) | ranges::to_vector;
```

but if all the function which you pass `evens` to does is to loop on it, then

```cpp
return vec | ranges::views::filter(whatever);
```

is just fine.

As regards life time considerations, a view is to a range of values what a pointer is to the pointed-to entity: if the latter is destroied, the former will be dangling, and making improper use of it will be undefined behavior. This is an erroneous program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;

auto f() {
    // a local vector here
    std::vector<std::string> vec{"zero","one","two","three","four","five"};
    // return a view on the local vecotor
    return vec | filter([](auto){ return true; });
} // vec is gone ---> the view returned is dangling

int main()
{
    // the following throws std::bad_alloc for me
    for (auto i : f()) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no restrictions on the usage of components of the STL in the standard. Of course, there are best practices (eg, `string_view` instead of `string const &`).

In this case, I can foresee no problems with handling the view return type directly. That said, the best practices are yet to be decided on since the standard is so new and no compiler has a complete implementation yet.

You're fine to go with the following, in my opinion:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<int> v) : vec(std::move(v)) {}

    auto getEvens() const
    {
        return vec | ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return ! (i % 2); });
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the _best practices (eg, `string_view` instead of `string const &`)_ is trying to suggest. Neither is a substitute for the other: you can't just change `string const&` to `string_view` and expect that the code works.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8snYfz95W).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ranges::any_view` as a type erasure mechanism for any range or combination of ranges.

```
ranges::any_view<int> getEvens() const
{
    return vec | ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return ! (i % 2); });
}
```

I cannot see any equivalent of this in the STL ranges library; please edit the answer if you can.

EDIT: The problem with ranges::any_view is that it is very slow and inefficient. See https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/714.

Answer (score 1):

I will not comment on RangesV3 so ranges::any_view is not an option.
Speaking only on the standard library ranges C++20 version.

So I encountered a similar issue when trying to use views as to return a non-owning view of selected elements and be able to use it with the same interface as a regular vector eg. not having to **double dereference** ( vector of pointers or iterators to the values.)
Here is the result of trying to use a view in a tokenizer method which gets rid of whitespace/newline tokens. REDUNDANT_TOKEN_KINDS is an initializer list of enums of the token types which will be filtered. eg.TokenType::whitespace
**Note: rvector is equivalent to std::vector in the code below.**

```
        auto sanitize(const rvector<Token>& tokens) {
        rvector<Tokenizer::token_iterator> sanitized;
        for (auto it = tokens.cbegin(); it != tokens.cend(); ++it) {

            if (std::any_of(REDUNDANT_TOKEN_KINDS.begin(),
                REDUNDANT_TOKEN_KINDS.end(),
                [it](TokenKind match) { return match == it->type(); })) {
                continue;
            };

            sanitized.push_back(it);
        }

        auto sanitized_view = sanitized | std::views::transform(
            [&tokens](token_iterator iter) -> const Token & {
            return *iter;});

        // Create a non-owning view of iterators using std::ranges::subrange
        return sanitized_view;
        }
```

Now, this works well but what is the return type ? What if I want to make a another method such as `parse_tokens(token_view_type token_view)`.
I cannot do this because I cannot determine the return type of the token view.

I can do this(**use the auto argument type**):

```
void parse_tokens(const auto & token_view)
```

But that is very ugly and unsafe code,and that means the rest of my codebase will have to depend on a single method sanitize() and it's unknown return type. I would have to pass around auto until I copy the elements of the range into a vector. I could **specify the concept of ranges::range in the argument**. Which is way better. But that still leaves us with the problem of the return type of sanitize() not being obvious to the programmer. Furthermore this will create extraneous template instantiations of the parse_tokens method.

```
auto parse_tokens(const std::ranges::range auto & token_view)
```

So in general I would say it is not advisable to return a range or a view as it will mean all further code will have to adapt to this pattern. Like you said it would be smarter to do all the algorithmic processing in an encapsulated environment(a method or collection of methods) then return the desired result as a vector of iterators or references.

My solution is to **instead return a vector of std::reference_wrappers containing the 'selected' or 'filtered' values**. Here is the code:

```
// Returns a non-modifiable vector of const references to the subrange of tokens which are not redundant.
    static const token_view sanitize(const rvector<Token>& tokens) {
        rvector<std::reference_wrapper<const Token>> sanitized;
        for (auto it = tokens.cbegin(); it != tokens.cend(); ++it) {

            if (std::any_of(REDUNDANT_TOKEN_KINDS.begin(), 
                REDUNDANT_TOKEN_KINDS.end(),
                [it](TokenKind match) { return match == it->type(); })) {
                continue;
            };

            sanitized.push_back(*it);
        }

        return sanitized;
    }
```

This has the small disadvantage of not being directly returnable when iterating, you have to call it->get() to get the underlying referenced object.

```
// Inside Parser class....
// Omitted code....
// token_view_iterator is of type :
// rvector<std::reference_wrapper<const Token>>::const_iterator
        const Token & get(token_view_iterator cursor) {
        if (cursor >= tokens_end()) {
            return Token{ TokenKind::eof };
        }
// Must do cursor->get() , cannot simply dereference *cursor
        return cursor->get();
    }
```

Overall the function is the same, and makes the code a lot more clear(isn't it beautiful?).  All the pointer logic is handled under the hood by std::reference_wrapper so you don't mess with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is desirable to declare a function returning a range in a header and define it in a cpp file

1. for compilation firewalls (compilation speed)
2. stop the language server from going crazy
3. for better factoring of the code

However, there are complications that make it not advisable:
[How to get type of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400374/how-to-get-type-of-a-view)

- If defining it in a header is fine, use `auto`
- If performance is not a issue, I would recommend `ranges::any_view`
- Otherwise I'd say it is not advisable.